# Excel 2007: Count backwards by month given a starting month

Tags: datetime, excel-2007

I am working in Excel 2007. My preference would be to do this without VBA. I am trying to count backwards a number of months starting from a given date.  For example:

```
Start Date: July, 2010
Countdown: 12 months
```

Should result in:

```
  Jun 2010
  May 2010
  Apr 2010
  Mar 2010
  Feb 2010
  Jan 2010
  Dec 2009
  Nov 2009
  Oct 2009
  Sep 2009
  Aug 2009
  Jul 2009
```

So the seed month is month 0 and the countdown period can vary.  I would like the month/year combination for display purposes but I also need the calculated value (ie, seed month is 0, next previous month is -1, etc) for calculations.

Any advice/help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's relatively simple. For example, in cell **A1**, put "July 2010". In **B1**, put `=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)-1,DAY(A1))` and in **C1** put either `=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)-2,DAY(A1))` or `=DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1)-1,DAY(B1))` and so on.

If you're looking for a `for/each` type of statement with the number of months in the countdown, you'll need to go to VBA. Otherwise, you can prepopulate a range of cells with code like the above (You can start it with an if statement if the countdown cell has nothing, to display nothing).

Comment: duh - sorry, if I knew it was that simple, I wouldn't have asked in this forum!  thanks Otaku!